# Use API to get a list of all services requests in the system

Tags: rest, tivoli

With this API, I can get a list of all **my** service requests:

```
http://localhost:9080/maxrest/rest/os/SRM_SR?_lid=maxadmin&_lpwd=maxadmin
```

*maxadmin is my credentials.*

Is there a way for me to get a list of all service requests in the system?

Here is a link to the page about API service requests: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFG5E_7.2.4/com.ibm.tsam_7.2.4.doc/r_sr.html

Answer (score 0):

I have found this solution:

```
http://localhost:9080/maxrest/rest/os/MXSR?_lid=maxadmin&_lpwd=maxadmin
```

I haven't seen that request documentet anywhere. If anyone finds documentation on it, then please add a link to this post.